# aframe 0.8.2 load VR as magic window/novr headset / enter in vr without splitting screen

Tags: javascript, aframe

I dont want to use normal magic window since some elements are not working in it since they are using raycaster through camera and that are working in vr mode so I want to enter the vr mode directly but not in split screen but like a magic window currently

A-Frame Version: 0.8.2
Platform / Device: Android 9.0 Pocophone F1 Google Chrome (latest version)

I am using this to directly enter the vr mode but i don't want to split screen

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').enterVR()
```

Comment: For reference. This has been addressed on Github: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want vr mode by default in portrait mode you can do this

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').enterVR()
document.querySelector('a-scene').exitVR()
```